# IDempiere Service Integration

Tags: adempiere, idempiere

I need to call Idempiere **Business Modules** (ex. Creating Purchase Order process) , **not tables** via a web services, Is there any way to do this without going through the source code of Idempiere, I don't want to use RESTful methods that will deal with tables directly

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to improvements on iDempiere's Web Services where composite (master-detail) and CRUD actions are now possible. Complete description at the project wiki: http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/NF1.0_Web_Services_Improvements
Below I paste results of https://test.idempiere.org/ADInterface/services

Available SOAP services:
CompositeService

```
compositeOperation

Endpoint address: http://test.idempiere.org/ADInterface/services/compositeInterface
```

WSDL : {http://idempiere.org/ADInterface/1_0}compositeInterface
Target namespace: http://idempiere.org/ADInterface/1_0
ModelADService

```
setDocAction
createUpdateData
getList
readData
createData
runProcess
queryData
deleteData
updateData

Endpoint address: http://test.idempiere.org/ADInterface/services/ModelADService
```

WSDL : {http://idempiere.org/ADInterface/1_0}ModelADService
Target namespace: http://idempiere.org/ADInterface/1_0

Available RESTful services:
Endpoint address: http://test.idempiere.org/ADInterface/services/rest
WADL : http://test.idempiere.org/ADInterface/services/rest?_wadl

Answer (score 0):

You can use create a provide service interface from org.adempiere.base plugin, invoke this service inside your code and invoke the constructor for class MOrder extends X_C_Order and for class MOrderLine extends X_C_OrderLine.

Here you have the example from IProcessFactory (you can create your factory like ICreateOrderFactory , or just IInsertFactory ( for a generic factory constructor you can set the table id  ) :

This is a interface declaration

```
public interface IProcessFactory {
    /**
     * Create new process instance
     * @param className
     * @return new process instance
     */
```

> ```
>   public ProcessCall newProcessInstance(String className);
> ```

```
    }
```

This is a evocation method

```
    public class ProcessFactory implements IProcessFactory {
    @Override
    public ProcessCall newProcessInstance(String className) {
        if (className.equals("com.com.nexus.webservice.client.process.IntegratorWS"))
            return new IntegratorWS();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now you need to create .xml of this factory like that : (pay attention in provided interface)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="com.nexus.integrator.ProcessFactory">
<implementation class="com.nexus.webservice.client.process.ProcessFactory"/>
<property name="service.ranking" type="Integer" value="5"/>
<service>
<provide interface="org.adempiere.base.IProcessFactory"/>
</service>
</scr:component>
```

To use this in OSGI architecture, you need to configure your MANIFEST file to import this
Service-Component: ( I always use osgi-inf directory for my factories xml)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: com.nexus.webservice.client
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nexus.webservice.client;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: Macrosoftware
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Require-Bundle: org.adempiere.base
```

> Service-Component: OSGI-INF/ProcessFactory.xml

```
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

You can do this , or you can use composite webservice .
I consider the second most safe and effective method